# How to accept user input with Sitecore DMS report/filter?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-dms

With the Sitecore OMS, it was possible to create custom report filters that used the Sitecore rules engine to accept user input. This was useful for filtering by ItemId, URL, IP Address, etc. [Here is an example](http://ivanbuzyka.blogspot.com/2010/10/create-custom-like-filter-for-analytics.html) of a custom filter for the OMS.

**How does one go about accepting user input with the Sitecore DMS?** It appears that the old filter methodology has been scrapped in lieu of "[Predefined Filters](http://webcmd.wordpress.com/2012/07/19/adding-site-filters-to-dms-reports-with-sitecore-6-5/)", which are hard-coded values that get injected into the SQL Statement's WHERE clause.

Comment: Do you mean this in terms of how you can let the report maker put in their own "filter" for data or do you mean how to add data specific to the user in the reports that may not be recorded automatically by DMS?

Comment: I would like the business user who is running the report to be able to enter an Item ID. We get many requests for "How is my page doing" and so far have been unable to run reports that are based on an individual Item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are aware that every item in Sitecore has the Analyze tab in which there is a "Reports" option where the user can see reports specific to the item?  I realize that these are really "canned" reports, but it's not too difficult to create new ones or adapt the existing ones to give you what you want to see.  If the reports aren't specific enough, you can always create your own reports and then just simply drop them into the item reports folder here:  /sitecore/system/Settings/Analytics/Reports/Item Reports/.  Also, keep in mind that all the SQL queries are located in items here:  /sitecore/system/Settings/Analytics/Reports SQL Queries  and it's not difficult to add a parameter (i.e. the date parameter for example).

I know that it has a bit of a learning curve, but creating your own queries and reports capable of taking some user input isn't out of the question.  Please let me know if you have something specific or if you need further help. I've spent a good amount of time doing custom reports and I'd be happy to answer any questions.

Comment: I was not aware, but I am now :)